# Need some hint with limit with multiple variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The limit
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^{1/3}y^2}{x+y^3} $$
does exist since when we set $y=0$, $x=0$, and $x=y$ (it all equals to $0$). So now we need to evaluate the limit. The L'Hospital rule does not apply with multiple variables, so I am stuck of how to approach it. I understand that I need to somehow manipulate it, but I have no idea how. Any hints?

Comment: Does it? What about the limits along the paths $x = y^3$ and $x = 2y^3$?

Comment: It doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that it exists? The fact that you get the same value of the limit along three different trajectories is **NOT** sufficient to conclude that the limit exists. The limit must be the same along **all** possible trajectories (approaching the given point). And you have only tried three, not all, so it's way too early to jump to any conclusions.

Hint: try the curve $x=y^3$ as the trajectory. To express the fact that $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along this trajectory, substitute $x=y^3$ and then find the limit as you let $y\to0$ (along this curve).